# SQL schema will not build - obscure error reference to syntax near ')'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, syntax-error

I'm learning mySQL and running into syntax errors that I can't seem to fix. I get an error that states that "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 8" line 8 being the declaration of `state`. 
I am checking my code with sqlfiddle and mySQL 5.6 with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
`customer_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`apartment` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`state` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`home_phone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`cell_phone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`other_phone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `donut` (
`donut_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`unit_price` int(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`donut_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `order` (
`order_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`customer_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`order_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`handling_notes` varchar(300),
PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `order_line` (
`order_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`donut_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`donut_quantity` int(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`, `donut_id`)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FOREIGN KEY` clause in the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `order`  misses a `REFERENCES` clause.

Presumably you want to replace

```
FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
```

with:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
            REFERENCES `customer`
                       (`customer_id`)
```

Comment: I see, I made the mistake of assuming that there would be enough preprocessing done by the mysql interpreter to know which table I am looking for. Thank you for the help!